# Linux ip-ip tunnel not working

Tags: ubuntu

An ip-ip tunnel between ubuntu 22 and a mikrotik router.

After an unknown period of time, tunnel will stop working.

just back once in linux pinging mikrotik side ip address.

i have to check eoip-tunnel also with same issue.

how do can fix problem?

Comment: So well, first of all don't just *describe* configuration, *show it* to us. Also check firewalls. And, finally, note that ipip tunnels are insecure unless externally secured by ipsec; never use ipip alone over untrusted networks. For that, use Wireguard which can be thought as a secure drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

That may be due to the same reason, why GRE tunnels Linux<->Mikrotik stop wotking at some point: Linux doesn't send keepalive packet, while Mikrotik is expecting it, and no any othe traffic goes through the tunnel for some time.

Solution is described here [GRE keepalive with Linux and RouterOS](https://serverfault.com/questions/547275/gre-keepalive-with-linux-and-routeros)

The other option may be to set maximum possible keepalive value on the Mikrotik side, which is 4294967295 according to docs. Or some people say at Mikrotik forums, that you can [undefine it](https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=110557) to completetely turn off, but i never tested it, so can't confurm.